# Where does Next.js store public keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In Next.js documentation  they say that:

> By default environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser.
> In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the
> variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_.
> `NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID=abcdefghijk`
> This loads process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID into the Node.js environment
> automatically, allowing you to use it anywhere in your code. The value
> will be inlined into JavaScript and sent to the browser because of the
> NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix. This inlining occurs at build time, so your
> various NEXT_PUBLIC_ envs need to be set when the project is built.

I have searched for the public keys in every JavaScript file injected by Next.js, and I can't see the public keys!

Does this mean keys prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC` are still unreachable? And we can store secret keys with `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix?

Comment: Do you use the variables in your frontend?

Comment: Knowing nothing of the technologies involved, I'll take a wild guess that the answer to "should we store secret keys with `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix" is a hard and strong **NO!**

Comment: TBH the question is unclear. You have a question in the title: _"Where does Next.js store public keys?"_ and a quote _"The value will be inlined into JavaScript and sent to the browser"_. If this is a generic question, you answered your own question. If this specific question, why this doesn't work for you, we need debugging details.

Comment: @jabaa I was searching in a wrong way, but the accepted answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public keys such as `NEXT_PUBLIC_ID=1f4g` acceded with `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ID` are replaced in the generated HTML and/or JavaScript files by their values, at build time.

So after launching a build, if you search for `1f4g` in the `.next` folder, you will find it, while you won't if you search for `NEXT_PUBLIC_ID`.

So  use `NEXT_PUBLIC` only for things that can be shown to users without any concern, as they say in the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser):

> In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. For example:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ID=1f4g
```

Comment: "if you search for 1f4g in the .next folder, you will find it, while you won't if you search for NEXT_PUBLIC_ID."

Thank you, this is very helpful, I tried this and it worked, I can find the private keys there.